# Whatsapp send text through the Windows Application

Tags: windows, whatsapp

Is there any method to call the Whatsapp Send API to send text through the PC Application? When I call https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=xxxxx&text=xxxxx, it didn't ask me to open the Windows application and redirected me to the Web Whatsapp. Is it the application association problem? Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)

Here is the answer. We need to create a new application association in windows.